# Making a .py executable but library of os dont work

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, pyinstaller

I make a .exe of my Python script with Pyinstaller, is a program to shutdown your pc when the input time arrive but when the time arrive he print "the computer" is gonna shutdown but nothing happen

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from msvcrt import getch, kbhit
from time import sleep
def get_down(time):
    print('press ENTER to cancel \n')
    while True:
        if kbhit(): 
            key = ord(getch()) 
            if key == 13:
                print('You cancel the operation ')
                break

        if time == datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M'):
            print("The system is gonna turn off")
            os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")

print('Now is: {}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial understanding is that you want to run a script that will turn your computer off at a specified time but can cancel it if you choose not to shutdown before then.

Based on that, I've made some modifications to your code.
The modifications are that you give the shutdown function a datetime when you want the system to shutdown. The function works out how many seconds that is in the future, then sleeps for that amount of time. If you want to cancel it, press Ctrl+C to cancel. When the sleep finishes, it should be the scheduled shutdown time, so we execute the shutdown command.

I added a `grace_time` argument to the function so that when I was testing my PC wouldn't instantly shutdown (which would have made debugging slower)!

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep


def shutdown_system(time: datetime, grace_time: int = 30):
    """
    :param time: time the system should be shut down
    :param grace_time: grace time before the shutdown command executes
    """
    # calculate the scheduled shutdown time in seconds
    sleep_time = (time - datetime.now()).total_seconds()

    print("System scheduled to shutdown at {}".format(time.isoformat()))
    print("Press Ctrl+C to cancel")

    try:
        # sleep the program for the time until the shutdown is scheduled
        sleep(sleep_time)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # a Ctrl+C will trigger this
        print("You cancelled the shutdown!")
        # return so shutdown doesn't continue
        return

    # Execute the shutdown command
    print("The system is going to shutdown in {} seconds".format(grace_time))
    os.system("shutdown /s /t {}".format(grace_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    now = datetime.now()
    shutdown_system(now + timedelta(seconds=1))
```